# How to remove Home Folder icon from desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, home-directory

When I start Ubuntu I had my "home/user" in my Desktop.

test is my User.

[image: home folder on desktop]

[image: home folder open in file manager]

How do I make the folder not be on the desktop?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Open the terminal and type the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
```

After you do this, the home folder icon should disappear from your desktop.

Comment: best answer, just copy/paste the command

Comment: And (in case it's not obvious) to remove just the "trash" icon copy and paste this command in the terminal -      
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false

Comment: Doesn't work: No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons”

Answer (score 16):

The easiet way would be to install the package.. `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`

Once you install the package, you can find the app in all apps..

[image]

and then turning off the switch for "Show the personal folder in the desktop"

[image]

[image]

Same thing can be achieved with `gnome-tweaks` also, If you already Installed `gnome-tweaks`

Comment: thx for reply, in that way I hide all, it's possible to hide or make disapeear only that folder. Btw one question if I did the installation in that way I mean the "partitioning" always I'll have my ("home/<user>") in my Desktop?, if i separe "/home" of course.

Comment: you want to hide only the `user` named Icon rite? in the above way I just see it is only hiding the `user` Icon. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsMAt.png

Comment: Hi, I just tried it in a fresh install by creating `/home` partition like you. Are you sure you are not looking for this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/olic5.png

Comment: yes, thx. One question if I separate `/home` when I "partitioning" always will appear the **personal folder** in the Desktop?

Comment: Yes it does not matter whether you mount it separately or leave it to root. That's why I did a fresh install and check it.

Comment: but this not happened before not?, I don't remember in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that this happened maybe I'm wrong.Thx for help rlly

Comment: in 18.04 the desktop/icons is controled by nautilus.. I think from 19.04/19.10 the desktop/icons are controlled by the above extension. `desktop-icons`

Comment: You mean `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` **?**, me too I like plain but I was strange looking that folder I was thinking that i did something wrong when I particioned the disk. Thx for explain me all related with desktop/icons.

Comment: the gnome-shell-extension named `desktop icons` is handling the desktop/icons. In 18.04 it is handled by nautilus/File Manager (Default). `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` is a tool to configure installed `gnome-shell-extensions`

Comment: The GNOME extensions app comes preinstalled on Ubuntu 20.04 - you shouldn't need to install it.

Answer (score 11):

To remove both the trash icon and home icon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
```

No need to install any additional software

Comment: Thanks for the post.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I came here without solution, but this answer for similar question solve it. I'm current in Ubuntu 21.10:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1335409/452437

In dconf application, after installed, I went to `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/ding/` and disable `show-home` option.

Comment: Yeah, this has apparently changed in 21.10.  I tried the *desktop-icons" mentioned above and it isn't present; apparently replaced with "ding".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the above mentioned commands in one line

**To hide to home and trash icons:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false && gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
```

**Just in case, to show those icons again:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home true && gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash true
```

Hope it helps.