# Ubuntu 21.04 remove trash, user and drive icon from desktop?

Tags: gnome, icons, trash, gsettings, 21.04

I want to remove the trash icon, the home icon as well as the drives from my desktop. I've removed them in Ubuntu 20.04, but after updating, they were there again:

I tried:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-trash false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false
```

> No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons”

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

> No output

But all icons are still there. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: `sudo apt install dconf-editor` will give you a graphical interface to explore, find (complete with search feature), and adjust the same settings.

Comment: Also [look up how your gnome-shell extensions are called now](https://askubuntu.com/q/1133782/1157519), and whether you can spot one responsible for the feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your help, I found the solution.

Comment: You can add it as an answer, so we could also learn the solution :)

Comment: Work in progress :)

Comment: Check https://fostips.com/remove-trash-icons-change-size-ubuntu-21-04/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [@Levente](https://askubuntu.com/users/1157519/levente)'s comment I found out the solution.

There is an application called "Extensions" which lets you manage the Gnome Extensions. You can just disable the pre-installed extension called "Desktop Icons NG (DING)" and the icons will disappear:

[image: Extentions]

Answer (score 6):

You can actually keep DING enabled. Then right-click the desktop and select the last item: "Desktop Icons settings". There you can control what DING does, for example remove the home and wastebasket icons :)

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: so much searching - this obviously the intended way to do this, its amazing how hard it is to find online. Thank you for posting the obvious answer!

Comment: This also works in Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Is there a similar setting for the trash icon on the taskbar?

Comment: @RomanSt if you mean the "dock" or whatever it is called, the launcher column on the screen left side, I don't know. That horrible thing is long gone from my screen, sorry ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com
```

Answer (score 3):

To hide the trash and home icons:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-trash false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-home false
```

To additionally hide the external drives:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-volumes false
```

Slightly off-topic, but I think it's nice to show hidden files when they are in the Desktop (so I can remove them or process them accordingly since in my workflow typically hidden files should not be there):

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true
```

Answer (score 1):

in Ubuntu 22.04 it's easy to remove the 'home' icon from the desktop:

1 - right click on your desktop
2 - select 'desktop icons settings'
3 - deselect 'show personal folder'